# Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread while runing a member method on another QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qthread

I need to run a method in my MainWindow class, in a different thread as it is a length and time consuming process.

This is what I tried:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    initGui(ui);

    // Create background worker thread
    backgroundWorker = QThread::create([this] {
        backgroundMethod();
    });

    // Define when finished with work
    connect(backgroundWorker, &QThread::finished, [this] () {
        qDebug() << "Background method has finished";

        // Stop movie
        ui->lblLoading->movie()->stop();

        // go to next screen
        ui->tabbarMainWidget->tabBar()->setCurrentIndex(1);

        //show backup icon files
        if(filesToBackup.size() > 0) {
            qDebug() << "There are files to backup!";
            ui->lblInfoImage->show();
        }
    });

    // Start worker thread
    backgroundWorker->start();
}
```

**backgroundMethod**

```
void MainWindow::backgroundMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        qDebug() << "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I am omitting alot of code as it is not necessary. The basic logic is as follows:

1. Start new thread using [QThread::create()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#create-1)
2. Run the `backgroundMethod()` until completed while having the UI free for other work.
3. When the `backgroundMethod()` has finished, the `QThread` should emit the [finished()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#finished) signal.
4. I have a connection setup between the `backgroundWorker` thread's `finished()` and the lambda to run some more code.

**The problem:**

> Background method has finished
>
> QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
>
> ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 0x0x2801d950. Receiver 'lblInfoImage'
>   (of type 'QLabel') was created in thread 0x0x2688c4b0", file
>   kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 578 04:11:28: The program has
>   unexpectedly finished.

In short, I am accessing the `lblInfoImage` on the `backgroundWorker` thread. I understood that using the [signal/slot mechanism](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) should cater for this issue, where my use of it is correct.

I am not sure why this is happening, **I need some help in understanding what I did to cause the problem and how I can fix it**

Comment: show the `backgroundMethod` method.

Comment: @eyllanesc updated

Comment: Your code does not help, provide a [MRE]

Comment: updated...again - the background method content should not make any difference. This is a question about the signal/slot mechanism using different threads. The content of the backgroundThread is of no essence.

Comment: Your code is not an MRE, I recommend you take your time and provide what you have been asked for if you want help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simple: you execute UI code on a non-UI thread which is strictly forbidden in Qt (and in many other UI frameworks across different languages). That happens because you do the connection wrong:

```
connect(backgroundWorker, &QThread::finished, [this] () {
    ...
});
```

That connection means: whenever `QThread` emits a `finished` signal run this function. The thing is, it will run the function in the context of the emitted signal which is another thread not the thread `backgroundWorker` lives in. So you have to provide the UI thread context for receiving this signal:

```
connect(backgroundWorker, &QThread::finished, this, [this] () {
        ...
    });
```

Now the function provided will be executed in the context of the UI thread (`this`).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understood that the [this] was to provide the context for the _workerThread_ to access the _UI Thread_. Hence, my confusion. I looked at `std::thread` examples and I noted that the context was passed in separately. Was going to try that next. Thank you!

Comment: @KGCybeX do not use `std::thread` with Qt until it really pays off somehow. And read how loops, events and threads interact in Qt. [That](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects) would be a good start.